# react-router link to element by id within another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router and I'm trying to link to a sub-component in another route by id. Basically what would usually be done using the `<a href="www.url.com/profile/#profile-header-id">.`

I'm not sure if there's a built in way for react router to do this, but if not perhaps I can manually trigger the link at a later point when I know the element has been rendered.

The issue isn't linking to another route which of course is done with the `Link` from react router. The issue is linking to an element which is found in the rendered HTML of the linked component.

**Less Abstract Code Example:**

So let's say my router is

```
<Route path"/A" component={A}>
<Route path"/B" component={B}>
```

component A has the following render:

```
render(){
  <div>
      // A looooot of text and other HTML elements
      <div id="relevant-to-B">
           // relevant stuff for component B
      </div>            
  </div>
}
```

Now in component B, I want a Link that not only takes me to the Route "/A", but also scrolls to the element of id  `#relevant-to-B`, thereby skipping all the irrelevant stuff.